# How Add Tab ability to Content Editor Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, content-editor-web-part

Hope you're well;

I would like to know how I can add tabs in **Content Editor** web part in SharePoint Online.

What is best solution to this.

*kind regards,
Anees*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jQuery tab to add tab functionality in SharePoint.

You can get more information on below link:
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/